# Stock market simulator with time compression

Tags: finance, simulation

I'm looking for a stock market simulator which is not real time. I want to be able to, for instance, go back to April 2005 and paper trade on the market as it looked back then (assuming the data is available). I also want to be able to fast forward - for instance if I pretend-buy a stock portfolio in 2007 and want to see what happens to it in 2009, I want to be able to quickly move 2 years forward and immediately see the effects.

Feature I'm looking for:

- Uses real data
- Reasonably intra-day resolution: I'm not looking to simulate HFT, but I want to be able to at least do day trades that are an hour long
- Must include at least the stocks in S&P 500, major indices (S&P, NASDAQ, DJI), major ETFs (sector-based, commodity-based, etc.)
- Must support options, at least buying/selling puts and calls, but ideally combinations as well
- Must simulate commissions
- Can be Windows or Android or both